# Quantitative estimate on continuity with respect to parameter of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Let $V:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, $\text{Holder}$ continuousfunction with degree $\delta\in (0,1]$ such that $\inf_{\mathbb{R}} V = 0$ but $V(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $r \geq 0$ be the parameter, we consider $\eta_r(s)$ be the solution to the following ODE:
$$ \begin{cases}
\dot{\eta_r}(s) &= \sqrt{r+V(\eta(s))}, \qquad{s>0},\\
\eta(0) &=0.
\end{cases}$$
I am concerning about the following question, as $r\rightarrow 0$, it is reasonable to expect $\eta_r \rightarrow \eta_0$ in somesense. Is there anyway we can quantify the difference of $\eta_r(s)$ and $\eta_0(s)$ in terms of $r$ and $s$, which guarantee that the two solutions are close to each other provided $r$ very close to 0?

Comment: You can explicitely write down the solution. Then you see that by dominated convergence you get pointwise convergence of the solution for $r\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I need an quantitative estimate uniformly in $r$, is it possible?

Comment: What kind of estimate are you looking for?

Comment: I need some estimates sort of $|\eta_r(t) - \eta_0(t)| \leq \rho(r,t)$ where $\frac{\rho(r,t)}{t} \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ uniformly in $r$.

Comment: I think your next solution is natural, I may try to use it. Thanks!

Comment: My solution was completely wrong, I am sorry for that. I'll think about a way to fix it.

Comment: I can only do the case where $V$ is lipschitz, I also don't see how to use the boundedness of $V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I only know how to do it for lipschitz functions. Also my estimate only gives locally uniformly convergence, but not the strong estimate you are looking for.**

Assume that $V$ is lipschitz.

Fix $s_0$ and say $0\leq s \leq s_0$. Then by assumption $c_0:= \min_{t\in [0;s_0]} V(\eta_0(s)) >0$ and we obtain for $r\geq 0$
$$ \vert \eta_r(s) - \eta_0(s) \vert =
\left\vert \int_0^s (\eta_r'(t)- \eta_0'(t)) dt \right\vert =
\left\vert \int_0^s \left(\sqrt{r+ V(\eta_r(t))} - \sqrt{ V(\eta_0(t)} \right) dt \right\vert 
= \left\vert \int_0^s \frac{r + V(\eta_r(t))- V(\eta_0(t))}{\sqrt{r+V(\eta_r(t))} + \sqrt{V(\eta_0(t))}} \right\vert.$$
We also know that $V$ is Lipschitz continuous, and hence we get
$$ \vert V(\eta_r(t))- V(\eta_0(t)) \vert 
\leq  C \vert \eta_r(t) - \eta_0(t) \vert $$
This yields
$$ \vert \eta_r(s) - \eta_0(s) \vert \leq \frac{rs}{\sqrt{c_0}} + \frac{C}{\sqrt{c_0}} \int_0^s \vert \eta_r(t) - \eta_0(t) \vert dt $$
Thus, we get from Gronwall's inequality 
$$\vert \eta_r(s) - \eta_0(s) \vert \leq \frac{rs}{\sqrt{c_0}} e^{s\frac{C}{\sqrt{c_0}}}.$$